# SQL Server : query with column named 'PLAN' executes but throws an error

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

We have a table with a column named `PLAN` which is a keyword. We are using brackets but the query still throws an error. Weird thing is the query still executes. The error makes the .net web context explode of course. Any ideas?

```
USE [SomeDB]

UPDATE [SomeTable] 
SET [SomeTable].[PLAN] = 2 
WHERE [SomeTable].[RECNUM] = 1
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PLAN'.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Error Message and what version of Sql server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3)

Comment: @DaveAvatar where are you executing this code? in SSMS?

Comment: @DaveAvatar do you have anything after this query, that is using `PLAN` as you can see from juergen's demo it does work by escaping the name?

Comment: Yup, that is it.  I had a stupid trigger on the table that I totally forgot about.  Bah.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It should work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a48b9/1). Must be something else.

Comment: Yup, that is it. I had a stupid trigger on the table that I totally forgot about. Bah. Thank you all.

Comment: So... the answer is "most be something else"... awesome.

Answer (score 0):

try this>

```
UPDATE [SomeTable] SET [PLAN] = 2 WHERE [RECNUM] = 1
```